# Use AWS keys to transfer data between organizations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to move client data from clients S3 bucket(s3://client-bucket) to our organizations S3 bucket(s3://org-bucket) I was given access keys to the clients S3 bucket.

Using AWS CLI i am able to access S3 bucket of client as see all files. I cannot however use aws s3 mv because the profile that has access to client-bucket does not have permissions set up for org-bucket.

I am not allowed to move data to an intermediate public bucket bc of security issues/sensitivity of data.

What is the best way of making this transfer go thru? Is there a way to set up a profile in aws cli config/credentials with both the access keys to org-bucket and client-bucket?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the access keys in your organization to access your client's S3 bucket. Since you need to copy objects directly via the `CopyObject` API, your IAM user/role needs to have access to both the S3 bucket in your org AND your client's S3 bucket. Therefore, your current approach doesn't work and even AssumeRole would not work either. You can follow [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/) guide to configure proper resource-based policies in S3.